# CLP libraries issue while configuring the Optic Planner

Tags: cmake, clp

I am facing CLP issue while configuring the optic planner. Please suggest how to overcome this issue.

Here is the issue:

```
arunkumar@arunkumar:~/Desktop/lwm2m_project_/planner/optic$ ./run-cmake-debug 
CMake Warning (dev) at optic/UseDoxygen.cmake:85 (add_custom_command):
  Policy CMP0040 is not set: The target in the TARGET signature of
  add_custom_command() must exist.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0040" for
  policy details.  Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and
  suppress this warning.

  No TARGET 'doxygen' has been created in this directory.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  optic/CMakeLists.txt:10 (include)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at optic/UseDoxygen.cmake:94 (get_target_property):
  Policy CMP0045 is not set: Error on non-existent target in
  get_target_property.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0045" for policy details.
  Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  get_target_property() called with non-existent target "doc".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  optic/CMakeLists.txt:10 (include)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Could NOT find Clp (missing:  CLP_LIBRARIES) 
-- Could NOT find CoinUtils (missing:  COINUTILS_LIBRARIES) 
-- Could NOT find Cbc (missing:  CBC_LIBRARY CBC_SOLVER_LIBRARY) 
-- Could NOT find Cgl (missing:  CGL_LIBRARIES) 
-- Could NOT find OSI (missing:  OSI_LIBRARIES) 
-- Could NOT find GSL (missing:  GSL_LIBRARIES) 
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
CBC_LIBRARY (ADVANCED)
    linked by target "optic-clp" in directory /home/arunkumar/Desktop/lwm2m_project_/planner/optic/src/optic
CBC_SOLVER_LIBRARY (ADVANCED)
    linked by target "optic-clp" in directory /home/arunkumar/Desktop/lwm2m_project_/planner/optic/src/optic
CGL_LIBRARIES (ADVANCED)
    linked by target "optic-clp" in directory /home/arunkumar/Desktop/lwm2m_project_/planner/optic/src/optic
CLP_LIBRARIES (ADVANCED)
    linked by target "optic-clp" in directory /home/arunkumar/Desktop/lwm2m_project_/planner/optic/src/optic
COINUTILS_LIBRARIES (ADVANCED)
    linked by target "optic-clp" in directory /home/arunkumar/Desktop/lwm2m_project_/planner/optic/src/optic
OSICLP_LIBRARIES
    linked by target "optic-clp" in directory /home/arunkumar/Desktop/lwm2m_project_/planner/optic/src/optic
OSI_LIBRARIES (ADVANCED)
    linked by target "optic-clp" in directory /home/arunkumar/Desktop/lwm2m_project_/planner/optic/src/optic

****-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!****
See also "/home/arunkumar/Desktop/lwm2m_project_/planner/optic/debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Comment: I have formatted your error message to be more readable. See [Editing Help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for how to do it yourself.

Comment: @Alex: It is better to format logs **as a code** (not as a *citation*). It is simpler (select whole log and press Ctrl+K) and preserves newlines in the view.